# ExtJS Ext.state.Manager.setProvider() behavior in 6.2 vs 4.x

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs6

I have an existing ExtJS application I'm upgrading from 4.x to 6.2.0. I had a simple storage provider setter that I pass into my `Ext.onReady()` block that looks like the following:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider',{}));
```

When I swapped to 6.2.0, I'd get the error:

```
ext-all-rtl-debug.js:9389 [E] Ext.util.LocalStorage.constructor(): Cannot create duplicate instance of local store "ext". Use Ext.util.LocalStorage.get() to share instances.
```

So what I had to do to, what I think is a fix, was the following:

`Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.util.LocalStorage.get('id'));`

My concern here though is that I'm just applying a bandaid to the problem and not really going through with a real fix. I don't explicitly set the provider anywhere else, all I did was swap out the ExtJS lib from 4.x to 6.2.0 to get that error. It's as-if it's being created somewhere else first in the 6.2.0 initialization process and now I'm getting a `duplicate` error as aforementioned.

What has changed in 6.2.0 to cause this behavior? Is there now two providers set, one by ExtJS and one with my client code? Is there a cleaner way of handling this?

Comment: I'd trace where it's setting the provider in the first place. Stick a break point where it's setting the id in `Ext.util.LocalStorage.cache`.

Comment: Can you make example [at the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Comment: have u tried it to put the setter, like described in the docs, during the init phase? (and not when ext is ready) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.state.Manager.html

Answer (score 2):

The preconditions for this error  are the same in both, ExtJS 4 and ExtJS 6. The corresponding file does not have changed: compare [ExtJS 4.2.4 version](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/source/LocalStorage2.html#Ext-util-LocalStorage) and [ExtJS 6.2.0 version](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/LocalStorage.js-1.html#Ext.util.LocalStorage).

Because of this your application must be responsible for this. Somewhere in your (upgraded) code an instance of `Ext.util.LocalStorage` must be created. Since this error is thrown in case the ID is already registered and the registration is done only in the constructor of the `Ext.util.LocalStorage` class, I'd suggest to set a breakpoint right there to check in the stacktrace which function does call the constructor method.